# Check function with IF statement in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

I have 10 functions, all 10 return '1' if the function has no errors and '0' if function has errors. I want to create another function witch calls all this functions and which checks it out if the functions return 0 or 1. After that, I want to run this function in linux crontab and the function's output (some text from if conditions) to go in a log file.
I'm not sure if I can check this functions like this. Thanks for your time!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_al1()
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100 

AS $BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    select public.test();
    if (select public.test()) = 1 then
        RAISE NOTICE 'No errors'
    else
        RAISE NOTICE 'Errors'
    end if;

END 
$BODY$;
```

Comment: `select public.test();` this line will fail because you can't do a `select` in plpgsql without a destination for the result.

Comment: And you don't even need a `SELECT`, especially when the function returns a scalar. Just `public.test()` is enough.

Comment: Ok, so is enough `public.test()`. IF statement is good? Can I make `(select public.test()) = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a return point for your query and there were also a few `;` missing. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve with this function, since you declared the function would return `TEXT` and there is no `RETURN` statement.

One option would be to not return anything and use [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) as you've been doing - keep in mind that the intention of `RAISE` (without `INFO`, `EXCEPTION`, etc.) alone is rather to report error messages:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_al1() RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
  IF public.test() = 1 THEN
    RAISE 'Errors';
  ELSE
    RAISE 'No errors';
  END IF;
END 
$BODY$;
```

.. or alternatively you can simplify it a bit by returning the message as `TEXT` in the `RETURN` clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_al1() RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE res TEXT DEFAULT 'No errors';
BEGIN 
  IF public.test() = 1 THEN
    res := 'Errors';
  END IF;
  RETURN res;
END 
$BODY$;
```

Further reading: [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: You don't even need the SELECT. `if public.test() = 1 then ...` should work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, silly me :-D thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thx! If I want to run `public.test()` before if statement is enough to put `....BEGIN 
 public.test() IF public.test() = 1 THEN...`?

Comment: @Lucian you don't need to run the function again before the if statement. Unless you store the result of this function a variable and compare this variable in your if statement. So, just execute your function once ;-)

Comment: Yea, bun I want to run this function (witch calls all 10 function and check then) every day at a specific hour using a bash script in linux crontab, i don't want to run this functions manually every day.

Comment: @Lucian in this case you'd perhaps be interested in calling all 10 functions and storing the results in a variable, something like: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_al1() RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE res TEXT DEFAULT '';
BEGIN 
  IF public.test() = 1 THEN 
    res := 'test() > fail';
  ELSE res := 'test() > pass'; END IF;    

  IF public.test2() = 1 THEN 
    res := res || E'\ntest2() > fail';
  ELSE res := res || E'\ntest2() > pass'; END IF;      
  RETURN res;
END 
$BODY$;`

Comment: depending on what you want to do with this result, consider returning a `table` so that you can iterate over the records ;-)